# Mass update of data in sql from int to varchar

Tags: sql, formatting, sql-server-2000

We have a large table (5608782 rows and growing) that has 3 columns Zip1,Zip2, distance

All columns are currently int, we would like to convert this table to use varchars for international usage but need to do a mass import into the new table convert zip < 5 digits to 0 padded varchars 123 becomes 00123 etc. is there a way to do this short of looping over each row and doing the translation programmaticly?

Comment: SQL is a data access language, not a product.  Each product implementing SQL has different particulars in how they work.  What product are you using?  The answers you get very much depend on *that*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example is assuming you are using MS SQL Server.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) for help on the replicate function.

```
insert  NewZipTable
        (Zip1,
        Zip2,
        Distance)
select  replicate('0', 5 - len(Zip1)) + CAST(Zip1 as VARCHAR(10)),
        replicate('0', 5 - len(Zip2)) + CAST(Zip2 as VARCHAR(10)),
        Distance
from    OldZipTable
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple RIGHT will do it in SQL Server

```
INSERT
    newTable (...
SELECT
    RIGHT('00000' + CAST(Zip AS varchar(5)), 5),
    ...
FROM
    OldTable
```

Comment: @GBN - for this to work, you'd have to cast to VARCHAR, not CHAR, otherwise your right 5 chars will be the int with space padding to 5 chars.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server....

try this, assumes nvarchar(20) for the new column:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable
       (col1, col2, col3
       ,NewZip)
    SELECT
        col1, col2, col3
        ,RIGHT(REPLICATE(N'0',20)+CONVERT(nvarchar(20),oldZip),20) --null will result in null
        FROM OldTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do such things in a loop, they can usually be done using pure SQL with much better performance.

Also, always store zip-codes and other things that can't be used for **calculations** as characters. Never heard of a 10% zip-code increase :)

---

Example using Oracle:

```
Insert Into new_table (zip1, zip2, distance)
    Select
        TO_CHAR( zip1, 'FM00000' ),
        TO_CHAR( zip2, 'FM00000' ),
        distance
    From old_table
```

Comment: You did not provide information about the database you are using, so I provided an `Example using Oracle` - as I wrote above the example :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO newTable (zip1, zip2, distance) 
SELECT LPAD(zip1, 5, '0'), LPAD(zip2, 5, '0'), distance
FROM oldTable;
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'LPAD' is not a recognized function name.

Comment: If it is MySQL (you didn't specify in the question), check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html for the usage. Other DBs will use a different but similar mechanism.